# Python updating 1 single element cause the entire column updated in a 2 dimentional array

Tags: python

I have a 10 by 10 matrix which has dic as element.
When I only want to update a single value, it ends up updating all values in that column.
Why? and How to fix it?

```
m = [[{}] * 10]*10

m[0][0] = {"a":1}
```

[image]

Is there an equivalent numpy style to do the same thing(if it could be quicker by using Numpy)?

Comment: You have a list of 10 references to one sublist, which is in turn a list of 10 references to one dict.  If you did `m[1][1]['a'] = 1` you'd see that reflected across all 100 nested elements.

Comment: An easy fix is to define `m` like: `m = [[{} for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: thanks @Samwise I just saw the reason and wonder why the 2nd 10 ([[{}] * 10]* **10**) makes the reference whereas the 1st 10 creates new variables??

Comment: It doesn't, but your `m[0][0] = {"a":1}` rebinds one of those references, which "fixes" the problem in that one spot.

Comment: @Samwise I tried this code `[[{}] * 10 for _ in range(10)]` and it also works.

Comment: It doesn't, not completely.  You should try the `m[1][1]['a'] = 1` that I suggested, since that will demonstrate both dimensions of the problem.

Comment: I tried, it does changed more than 1 element values, but it only affects the 1st row. I am really confused.  Do we have a way to use numpy to create a 10 by 10 dict type 2D array?

Comment: thanks @Samwise I decided to use the code you suggested as it works well.

Comment: Hi @Samwise , do you want to post your code as the answer?

Comment: The linked dupe already covers it.  :)